# Why is my flipview not showing any pictures?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, bitmapimage, flipview

Currently I am able to select multiple files but when I click open, the selected images are not being shown. Instead, "Windows.UI.XAML.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage" appears as a text. The `FlipView` functionality is still there though. What am I doing wrong?

XAML.

```
<FlipView x:Name="flpView" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10">
    <Image x:Name="images" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
</FlipView>
```

Behind code.

```
public async Task flipviewload()
{
    // Add code to perform some action here.
    Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    openPicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

    // Filter to include a sample subset of file types.
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    var files = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

    var images = new List<BitmapImage>();
    if (files != null)
    {
        //foreach (StorageFile Images in files)
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            using (Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream filestream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
                //Images.Source = bitmapImage;
                images.Add(bitmapImage);
            }
        }
    }
    flpView.ItemsSource = images;
}
```

I also added `Task foo = flipviewload();` in my public `MainPage();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this result because default rendering calls `ToString()` on the item, which prints the name of the class. If you want to display the image you have to supply an `ItemTemplate`:

```
<FlipView x:Name="flpView" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```