# Flip View Data Binding and file permissions

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

I am learning the basics of UWP and app making in Windows 10. 
I am trying to make a flip view with data that is pulled off a folder. It didn't display any images, so I tried manually adding images like so,

```
PrivateSet_images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Spot/1.png")));
PrivateSet_images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Spot/2.png")));

PrivateSet_images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Spot/jpg.jpg")));
PrivateSet_images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Spot/jpeg.jpeg")));
PrivateSet_images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Spot/jpg.png")));
PrivateSet_images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Spot/jpeg.png")));

PrivateSet_images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("F:\\Test Sp Folder\\1.png")));
PrivateSet_images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("F:/Test Sp Folder/1.png")));
```

All the ms-appx assets are read and displayed successfully (so not a file-type / file-extension problem). As for permissions to the folder, I used a folder picker to access a few files, so there are no permission issues (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)). I checked the debugger, and the files are read properly, but the last two aren't displayed (which point to the same file, I wanted to make sure it wasn't the `'/'` or `'\\'` preventing them from being displayed.)

XAML Code:

```
<FlipView x:Name="FlipViwe"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Images}" Visibility="Visible">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </DataTemplate> 
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

I don't seem to be able to solve this with solutions or similar questions like [Bind a Collection as ItemsSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450252/flipview-howto-bind-a-collectionstring-as-itemssource), [Flipview not showing any pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852459/why-is-my-flipview-not-showing-any-pictures) and [Show image files from a directory in a Flipview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389465/how-to-show-image-files-from-a-directory-in-a-flipview)
What am I missing?
Thank You.

Comment: Could you please give more information on F:\.  Is F a local drive or a remote drive?

Comment: @StuartSmith F: is a local hard disk partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,
So with the answer form @Jayden, I managed to find a solution. 
Here goes,
In a UWP app, using direct paths to files *may fail, reasons being either permissions, or the path being, as I like to put it, 'Virtual Directory'. One example is the Photos or the Music collection. All the files are populated and 'sent' to the requesting app. Also, the files may be from an another app. So storing the strings is pointless.

> Protected view for files is provided by the `StorageItems` classes (i.e. `StorageFolder` and `StorageFile`). `StorageItems` are the canonical storage identifiers for Windows Store apps, not the path. Your life (and your app) will be easier if you think and work in terms of StorageItems rather than trying to convert back and forth between `StorageItems` and paths. A key property of the `StorageFile` is that it isn’t restricted to file system objects. For example, a `StorageFile` can represent a photo “file” the user selected from another app via the file picker contract . The app deals with the `StorageFile` and doesn’t need to know or care if the data originated on disk or in another app. Conversely, apps which demand to know where the data originated can run into trouble: the `StorageFile` may not have a Path or may have a non file-system path.

So to overcome that, one has to use `StorageFile`, that guarantees access to files (assuming you already have permissions  to it). Also remember to store your access-permission!

> The `Windows.Storage.AccessCache` namespace provides classes to remember `StorageItems` so they can be reloaded later without requiring the user to go through the picker. The `StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList` provides random access to items that have been previously used. The `MostRecentlyUsedList` allows keeping a list of recently used locations.

After going through multiple examples and countless trials, I hit upon the solution, which I realized is similar to a linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852459/why-is-my-flipview-not-showing-any-pictures?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
public async void ImageViewGenerateAsync () {
var ImagesFolder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.
                          FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync("FolderFoken");

var ImgFiles = await ImagesFolder.GetFilesAsync();
foreach( StorageFile file in ImgFiles ) {
    if (file != null ) {
        try {
            var filestream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            var img = new BitmapImage();

            await img.SetSourceAsync (filestream);
            PrivateSet_images.Add(img);
        }
        catch ( Exception ) {                           
        }
    }
}
```

It, instead of accessing the files through strings and Uri, uses `StorageFile` that handles giving the file to you. Then read the files through `OpenAsync` and set this stream as the source of the BitmapImage (Described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Image_Source), scroll down to *Using a stream source to show images from the Pictures library*). I'm not sure of this is an optimized solution, but it works. I'd love to see if there is a better and optimized solution.

XAML:

```
<FlipView x:Name="FlipViweSpotlight"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Images}" Visibility="Visible">
<FlipView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</DataTemplate>

</FlipView.ItemTemplate>
```

This is a rudimentary solution that I came up with, any improvements / optimizations would be welcome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The UWP apps do not have permission to access all files on the device. By default, apps can access certain file system locations such as application install directory or application data locations. For more info, please see [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

`"F:\Test Sp Folder\1.png"` is a location that you app can't directly access. While dealing with files or folders in UWP, one important rule is [Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/).

It is recommend to use a `Folder​Picker` to let the user pick the folder and add it to your app's [`FutureAccessList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions#Windows_Storage_AccessCache_StorageApplicationPermissions_FutureAccessList) or [`MostRecentlyUsedList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions#Windows_Storage_AccessCache_StorageApplicationPermissions_MostRecentlyUsedList), in this way the they can be reloaded later without requiring the user to go through the picker. For more information, please check: [How to track recently-used files and folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh972344(v=win.10).aspx).

Comment: I went through the _Skip the Path_ article, and realized working with paths directly is not guaranteed to work (Thanks!). I'll update you soon with my success or failure. But I previously accessed files from the mentioned directory, so there is no problem in terms of access permissions. If I had not had access permissions to the folder, the last Uri's would've thrown an Exception. No exception, so I'm assuming I'm good regarding access.

Comment: I found an answer, thanks to your heads-up! I detailed my findings as an answer.